# Saving multiple default printer settings to a data file

Tags: mfc

I am not sure of the best place to ask this question, so if this is the wrong forum please advise.

I have the following two methods in a `MFC` derived project that I use for saving printer settings:

```
void CCommunityTalksApp::RestorePrinterSettings()
{
    DWORD       dwSize, dwVersion;
    LPVOID      lpData;
    DEVMODE     *pDevMode;
    HANDLE      hPrinter;
    CFile       fileIn;
    CString     strError, strTag;
    CWaitCursor wait;

    // open file
    if(!fileIn.Open(GetPRNPath(), CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary))
    {
        // unable to open file
        return;
    }

    CArchive    ar(&fileIn, CArchive::load);

    ar >> strTag;
    if (strTag != _T("PTS-Printer Settings"))
    {
        // old-style printer file
        return;
    }
    ar >> dwVersion;

    // free existing memory and assign to NULL
    if(m_hDevMode != NULL)
    {
        ::GlobalFree(m_hDevMode);
        m_hDevMode = NULL;
    }

    if(m_hDevNames != NULL)
    {
        ::GlobalFree(m_hDevNames);
        m_hDevNames = NULL;
    }

    // read in size of m_hDevMode structure and the structure data
    ar >> dwSize;

    // allocate memory for the structure
    m_hDevMode = ::GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwSize);
    if(m_hDevMode != NULL)
    {
        lpData = ::GlobalLock(m_hDevMode);
        ar.Read(lpData, dwSize);
        ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode);
    }

    // read in size of m_hDevNames structure and the structure data
    ar >> dwSize;

    // allocate memory for the structure
    m_hDevNames = ::GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwSize);
    if(m_hDevNames != NULL)
    {
        lpData = ::GlobalLock(m_hDevNames);
        ar.Read(lpData, dwSize);
        ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevNames);
    }

    ar.Close();
    fileIn.Close();

    // we must now validate the printer settings
    if(m_hDevMode != NULL)
    {
        pDevMode = (DEVMODE*)::GlobalLock(m_hDevMode);

        if(!OpenPrinter((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)pDevMode->dmDeviceName, &hPrinter, NULL))
        {
            strError.Format(ID_STR_INVALIDPRINTER_TPL, pDevMode->dmDeviceName);
            if(AfxMessageBox(strError, MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
            {
                // delete settings file
                DeleteFile(theApp.GetPRNPath());
            }

            ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode);
            // no printer found, so release memory and set to NULL
            if(m_hDevMode != NULL)
            {
                ::GlobalFree(m_hDevMode);
                m_hDevMode = NULL;
            }

            if(m_hDevNames != NULL)
            {
                ::GlobalFree(m_hDevNames);
                m_hDevNames = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // printer settings must be OK
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode);
        }
    }
}

void CCommunityTalksApp::SavePrinterSettings()
{
    CFile   fileOut;
    SIZE_T  dwSize;
    LPVOID  lpData;

    if(m_hDevMode == NULL && m_hDevNames == NULL)
    {
        // nothing to save
        return;
    }

    // create file
    if(!fileOut.Open(GetPRNPath(), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::typeBinary))
    {
        // unable to create printer file
        return;
    }

    CArchive    ar(&fileOut, CArchive::store);
    CString     strTag;

    strTag = _T("PTS-Printer Settings");

    ar << strTag;
    ar << (DWORD)100; // 1.00 (printer settings has it's own version number)

    // write out m_hDevMode size and structure
    if(m_hDevMode != NULL)
    {
        dwSize = ::GlobalSize(m_hDevMode);
        lpData = ::GlobalLock(m_hDevMode);

        BOOL bResetCopies = (BOOL)GetNumberSetting(
            _T("Preferences"),_T("ResetPrinterCopies"),FALSE);
        if (bResetCopies)
        {
            // Convert to DEVMODE structure and alter
            PDEVMODE pDevMode = (PDEVMODE)lpData;
            pDevMode->dmCopies = 1;
        }

        // write out size of structure
        ar << dwSize;

        // write out structure
        ar.Write(lpData, (UINT)dwSize);

        ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevMode);
    }

    // write out m_hDevNames size and structure
    if(m_hDevNames != NULL)
    {
        dwSize = ::GlobalSize(m_hDevNames);
        lpData = ::GlobalLock(m_hDevNames);

        // write out size of structure
        ar << dwSize;

        // write out structure
        ar.Write(lpData, (UINT)dwSize);

        ::GlobalUnlock(m_hDevNames);
    }

    ar.Close();
    fileOut.Close();
}
```

The above code works fine. The issue is when the user installs the program on *another computer* in a different location, which has a *different printer*.

The user *backs up* data files using a feature in my program and *restores* it on the other computer. As a result the *printer settings* are *overwritten* and when you start the program it raises a warning to *reset the the printer settings*.

Is it possible to support *multiple default printer settings* in a data file? And then have the ability at start up, using a valid printer from the data file?

If my question is off topic I will remove it at your request.

Comment: I think it's too risky to save `m_hDevMode` as binary and reload it. You should save individual settings, like printer's number of copies, printer orientation etc. and save/reload those values instead. Also this cast looks suspicious `(LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)pDevMode->dmDeviceName`, you shouldn't need any cast

Comment: So, perhaps use a XML file and store settings that way? But I would have to serialize all values of the `PDEVMODE` structure ...

Comment: I saw this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709297/A-Small-Class-for-Saving-and-Restoring-Users-Print?msg=5500900#xx5500900xx but again it is designed from what I can tell to store just one printer. I could be wrong. I need to investigate.

Comment: Does that even work? For example if you select landscape orientation, does it remember landscape for the next print session? I think you have to call `AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults` or something similar. But you are just calling `OpenPrinter` and `ClosePrinter`.

Comment: Yes it does work. Has for years. Because it is replacing the native member variables in the app class.

Comment: Oh I see, that's derived from `CWinApp`.  I wouldn't bother with XML. You can use the current method which already saves all the settings. But assign the settings manually when loading data. For example `pDevMode->dmFields |= DM_COPIES; pDevMode->dmCopies = oldvalue;`